# How to remove extra space from Alert dialog in android

Tags: android

In My android app, It is an alert dialog but there is one problem It have extra space from top of the title . How to remove extra space can anyone help me.

[image: In this image there is an alert dialog but I want to remove extra spaces from above welcome title]

```
java code

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_from);

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);

    Typeface tfmain = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontFooterpath);
    Typeface tfContent = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontMain);

    CustomTFSpan tfSpan = new CustomTFSpan(tfContent);
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("Welcome");
    spannableString.setSpan(tfSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    builder.setTitle(spannableString);

    CustomTFSpan tfSpan1 = new CustomTFSpan(tfmain);
    SpannableString spannableString1 = new SpannableString("Hello");
    spannableString1.setSpan(tfSpan1, 0, spannableString1.length(), spannableString1.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    builder.setMessage(spannableString1);

    builder.setPositiveButton("START", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Intent ii = new Intent(WelcomeFromActivity.this, Question1Activity.class);
            startActivity(ii);
        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false); //for prevent outside touch
    builder.show();

}
```

Can anyone know that how to remove extra space from alert dialog title.

Comment: Have you tried setting a custom view ?

Comment: yes but I can not get exact UI @Stefan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom style for your AlertDialog.

Add the following style to your style.xml.

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>     
</style>
```

Set the theme to your AlertDialog in the activity:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyCustomTheme);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are server ways:-

1. **Alert Dialog**

   ```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityContext, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar); // To remove extra space
        } else {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityContext);
        }

   builder.setTitle(dialogTitle);
   builder.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dialog.dismiss(); // Close dialog
          }
       });
   builder.setCancelable(false); //to make Dialog's outside non-touchable
   builder.show(); // to show dialog
   ```
2. **Custom Dialog**

   Make Custom Design in style.xml file and you can add more values according to your requirement.

   ```
   <style name="CustomDesign" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">>
         <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
         <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
         <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
         <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>
   ```

   Give this style to Alert Dialog or any dialog.

   For Alert Dialog  :-

   ```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder =
       new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.CustomDesign);
   ```

   For Dialog :-

   ```
   Dialog customDialog= new Dialog(this,R.style.CustomDesign);
   ```
3. **Dialog**

   ```
   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
   dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // To remove extra space
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout); // to set custom layout
   dialog.show();
   ```

Comment: Could you help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993190/alertdialog-remove-unnecessary-space?noredirect=1#comment113161344_63993190